# Working with same data in three activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm not very experienced in android specific components, so I just can't get where I need to look.

I have three activities:

1st gets info about some groups of objects, user selects some of this groups and activity needs to star next activity

2nd activity shows all objects from groups, that user selected at previous activity, here user can deselect some selected objects and then activity starts 3d activity

3d activity allows user to do something with selected objects

My solution is make some singleton model, that let activities get and save information about objects,

but i suppose, that android has some special components to provide data between activities

Help me to find this components^ please

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the type of data that you want to share:

**Primitive Data Types**
To share primitive data between Activities/Services in an application, use Intent.putExtras(). For passing primitive data that needs to persist use the Preferences storage mechanism.

**Non-Persistent Objects**
For sharing complex non-persistent user-defined objects for short duration, the following approaches are recommended:

**The android.app.Application class**

The android.app.Application is a base class for those who need to maintain global application state. It can be accessed via getApplication() from any Activity or Service. It has a couple of life-cycle methods and will be instantiated by Android automatically if your register it in AndroidManifest.xml.

**A public static field/method**

An alternate way to make data accessible across Activities/Services is to use public static fields and/or methods. You can access these static fields from any other class in your application. To share an object, the activity which creates your object sets a static field to point to this object and any other activity that wants to use this object just accesses this static field.

**A HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects**

You can also use a HashMap of WeakReferences to Objects with Long keys. When an activity wants to pass an object to another activity, it simply puts the object in the map and sends the key (which is a unique Long based on a counter or time stamp) to the recipient activity via intent extras. The recipient activity retrieves the object using this key.

**A Singleton class**

There are advantages to using a static Singleton, such as you can refer to them without casting getApplication() to an application-specific class, or going to the trouble of hanging an interface on all your Application subclasses so that your various modules can refer to that interface instead.

But, the life cycle of a static is not well under your control; so to abide by the life-cycle model, the application class should initiate and tear down these static objects in the onCreate() and onTerminate() methods of the Application Class

**Persistent Objects**
Even while an application appears to continue running, the system may choose to kill its process and restart it later. If you have data that you need to persist from one activity invocation to the next, you need to represent that data as state that gets saved by an activity when it is informed that it might go away.

For sharing complex persistent user-defined objects, the following approaches are recommended:

- Application Preferences
- Files
- contentProviders
- SQLite DB

If the shared data needs to be retained across points where the application process can be killed, then place that data in persistent storage like Application Preferences, SQLite DB, Files or ContentProviders.

Comment: "... so to abide by the life-cycle model, the application class should initiate and tear down these static objects in the onCreate() and onTerminate() methods of the Application Class" - I agree with the rest of the post, but feel that I should point out that the onTerminate() method is never called on actual devices (quote from the Android reference): "This method is for use in emulated process environments. It will never be called on a production Android device, where processes are removed by simply killing them; no user code (including this callback) is executed when doing so."

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can send data between activities using Intents. Using the `putExtra()` function for that. If you want to pass your own objects, you need to implement `Parcalable` class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with using a singleton to share information between your Activities, especially if you need this data to be consistent throughout your whole app.

Alternatively you could use an Intent to pass data between Activities - `putExtra()`.

Comment: I think it's not best idea to pass large arrays of objects through intent's extra

Comment: I agree, but he asked for other ways of passing data between Activities, so I let him know. I personally think that using a singleton is the best for sharing between Activities, as long as it's used properly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does:
http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a33/Passing-Bundles-Around-Activities.html

Basically you can either send a `Bundle` or just use `putExtra` function for that.

Answer (score 1):

try this way please

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, YourTragetedActivity.class);

    i.putExtra("value1", "test1");
    i.putExtra("value2", "test2");

    startActivity(i);


   //// On Your TragetedActivity

   getIntent().getStringExtra("value1")
   getIntent().getStringExtra("value2")
```